# Use Switch Block for 3 different values with Matlab Simulink

Tags: matlab, model, simulink

[image: model]

I have a model (depicted above) with a Switch which has 2 inputs y. One input y can take enumerated values "Green" or "Orange" and the other one can take enumerated values "Green" or "Red". I would like to know how with a switch (or another solution) can I have in output:

Green + Green = Green

Red + Green = Red

Orange + Green = Orange

Red + Orange = Red

Comment: Yes.  See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344853/8239061) or [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75491/476162).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign values as follows

```
Green = 1
Orange = 2
Red = 3
```

Then all of your conditions are satisfied by using a `max` block, with the 2 inputs from your function blocks...

```
Green + Green = Green
% max( 1, 1 ) = 1
Red + Green = Red
% max( 3, 1 ) = 3
Orange + Green = Orange
% max( 2, 1 ) = 2
Red + Orange = Red
% max( 3, 2 ) = 3
```